# what is the qualifier type and value?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

so I don't know how to import these photos in my android studio project.. I learn from android developers and in the explanation they imported the photos simply but I think the problem is the explanation from 2020... so please answer me
[I don't understand what to enter in qualifier type and value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tChh6.png)

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question must be clear and have enough details so that the community can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Qualifiers are a way of providing alternative resources to the Android System by the developer when he/she makes the app
You can choose not to have a qualifier at all

You can read in detail about the different qualifiers [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources)

Also in your case, just click Next and proceed with the flow

Alternatively, you can right click the `drawable` folder, click `Show in Files` and add the drawable there directly if you know what you are doing

Comment: can you show me the page which I choose not to have a qualifier because I made a new project and I didn't see it